# How do I solve this problem in github please

Tags: github, cmd, git-add

I'm getting this warning anytime I try to git add . all my file in my folder: warning: in the working copy of 'calculator-app-main/.gitignore', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it

I try using the normal method doing

```
git init 
git add .
```

so it suppose add all my file but it was that warning message I was getting

so my question is how can I solve this kind of issues anytime it pop out again

Answer (score -1):

Do this

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```